# How to load the rest of the data in mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have trouble figuring out how do I load the rest of the data in  html. Here is my code:

```
    <?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","nitoryolai123$%^");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("school", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$_GET['id']'");
?>     


                       <?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>

                                 <table class="a"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#D3D3D3">
<tr>
<form name="formcheck" method="post" action="updateact.php" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
<td>
<table  border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
<tr>

<td  colspan="16" height="25"  style="background:#5C915C; color:white; border:white 1px solid; text-align: left"><strong><font size="2">Update Students</td>


<tr>
<td width="30" height="35"><font size="2">*I D Number:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="idnum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/ value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30" height="35"><font size="2">*Year:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="yr" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/ value="<?php echo $row["YEAR"]; ?>"></td>
```

this is the part where I am getting the error:

```
mysql_select_db("school", $con);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$_GET['id']'");
    ?>
```

What do you recommend that I could do so that I can also load the ID Numbers corresponding data into the other forms?

Comment: Umm, this is a classic SQL injection security bug. Never ever use $_GET or $_POST or $_REQUEST or any sort of direct user input in an SQL-query directly, without first escaping it or sending it trough a filtering method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this,

```
  mysql_select_db("school", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".$_GET['id']);
```